# Can stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset be animated on while the next page is loading in iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, svg, mobile-safari, css-animations

I have an SVG animation that runs on a user sign in. It animates as expected in all browsers I have tested except for Safari in iOS. When the sign in is being processed before the next page is loaded, the animation's CSS `rotate()` property shows as intended, but the `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` do not run unless I stop the page load by tapping the "x" in the url bar. Then, the animation shows as intended.

I've tried animating the stroke on a `<path>` instead of a `<circle>`, animating using inline styles applied through javascript upon adding the element, removing the `rotate()` animation, applying the stroke animation in the exact same way as the `rotate()` animation, applying the CSS animations to separate elements in the `svg`, along with many other attempts-none of which get this stroke animation to show when the sign in (or other action requiring a page load) is initiated. This leads me to believe it has to do with stroke animations being handled differently in iOS.

Interestingly, the CSS rotate() transition was not showing on page load until I set the animation state to `running` using javascript (even though it should be running immediately when it is added to the page and it does in any other browser):

`svg.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = 'running';`

Unfortunately, applying this to the stroke animation in the same way has no effect.

I think this may be due to iOS prioritizing resources in some way, but I can't find any documentation in Apple's dev documentation or anywhere else explaining how or why rotate is handled differently than stroke animations.

I would have liked to set up an example somewhere, but I don't know a good way to simulate a page load in any of the code sharing sites.

Here is how this is being added to the page upon form submit:

```js
element.innerHTML = '<div class="loader"><svg id="container" class="container"><circle id="path" cx="22" cy="22" r="16" fill="none"></circle></svg></div>';
```

And the css animation (in Sass):

```css
.container
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 200
    stroke-dashoffset: 0
    stroke-opacity: 1
    stroke-width: 3
    stroke: $white
    stroke-linecap: round
    stroke-miterlimit: 10
    animation: ksrotate 2s linear infinite, ksdash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite
    -webkit-animation: ksrotate 2s linear infinite, ksdash 1.5s ease-in-out 


@-webkit-keyframes ksrotate 
    100% 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
        transform: rotate(360deg)

@keyframes ksrotate 
    100% 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg)
        transform: rotate(360deg)

@-webkit-keyframes ksdash 
    0% 
        -webkit-stroke-dasharray: 1, 200
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 0
        stroke-dasharray: 1, 200
        stroke-dashoffset: 0

    50%
        -webkit-stroke-dasharray: 89, 200
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: -35
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200
        stroke-dashoffset: -35

    100%
        -webkit-stroke-dasharray: 89, 200
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: -124
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200
        stroke-dashoffset: -124

@keyframes ksdash 
    0% 
        -webkit-stroke-dasharray: 1, 200
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: 0
        stroke-dasharray: 1, 200
        stroke-dashoffset: 0
    50%
        -webkit-stroke-dasharray: 89, 200
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: -35
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200
        stroke-dashoffset: -35

    100% 
        -webkit-stroke-dasharray: 89, 200
        -webkit-stroke-dashoffset: -124
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200
        stroke-dashoffset: -124
```